# SQL grammar definition, confusing notation

Tags: python, yacc, ply

I cannot figure out what this grammar definition is saying.

I am looking over the BNF for SQL grammar supplied here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/BNF+for+SQL+Grammar

I do not understand this grammar here for 'quoted_id':

```
quoted_id = <id_part> | "\"" ("\"\"" | ~["\""])+ "\""
```

I came up with a (seemingly) working implementation of 'id_part' that passes a dozen or so test cases:

```
# id_part = ("@" | "#" | <letter>) (<letter> | "_" | <digit>)*
def p_id_part(p):
    """
    id_part : AT
            | POUND
            | LETTER
            | AT id_end
            | POUND id_end
            | LETTER id_end
    """
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = p[2]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]


def p_id_end(p):
    """
    id_end : LETTER id_end
           | USCORE id_end
           | DIGIT id_end
           | empty
    """
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = p[2]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]
```

I have all the tokens I need, but I cannot seem to understand the grammar definition for 'quoted_id'. Maybe someone could explain what it actually covers? What I am mostly confused about is all the escaped characters, and what quotations are actually in the grammar.

Comment: The `quoted_id` rule says that these are valid quoted IDs: `abc` (quotes are not necessary), `"abc"` (case-sensitive), `"abc""def"` (a single identifier, with one double quote in the middle), `""""` (an identifier consisting of one double quote), `"[apoplexy]4]uU{{}"`, etc.  The `~["\""]` bit seems to mean what might be expressed as `[^"]` in many regex languages — anything that isn't a double quote.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler alright thank-you, this helps me understand it better.